# Search result comes out at the top of the page

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have not been able to make the search result appear below the search button on the page.
I have not found a way to show the result in the tbody of the view, without trying to call the method in the model to make a while error.

this is controller/clienteController.php

```
<?php
include_once 'model/cliente.php';
class clienteController{
private $model;
public function __CONSTRUCT(){
$this->model = new cliente();
}
public function Paginar(){
require_once 'view/header.php';
require_once 'view/cliente/cliente.php';
}

public function buscar(){
$cliente = new cliente();
if(isset($_POST['dni'])){
$cliente = $this->model->Buscarme($_POST['dni']);
}
require_once 'view/header.php';
require_once 'view/cliente/cliente.php';
}
}
```

this is model/cliente.php

```
  <?php
  class cliente
  {
  private $pdo;
  public $id;
  public $dni;
  public $Nombre;
  public $Apellido;  
  public $Correo;
  public $Telefono;
  public $res;
  public function __CONSTRUCT()
  {
  try
  {
  $this->pdo = conectar();     
  }
  catch(Exception $e)
  {
  die($e->getMessage());
  }
  }
  public function Buscarme($dni)
  {
  try {
  $stm = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE dni = :dni");
  $stm -> bindParam(':dni', $dni, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stm -> execute();    
  $res = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  foreach($res as $row){
  echo  $row['id'] . '</br>';
  echo  $row['dni'] . '</br>';
  echo  $row['Nombre'] . '</br>';
  echo  $row['Apellido'] . '</br>';
  echo  $row['Correo'] . '</br>';
  echo  $row['Telefono'] . '</br>';
  } 
  } catch (Exception $ex) {
  die($e->getMessage());
  }
  }
  }
```

the data is sent to this view view/cliente/cliente.php

```
<h1 class="page-header">CRUD con el patrón MVC en PHP POO y PDO </h1>
<a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" href="?c=cliente&  =agregar">Agregar</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" href="?c=cliente&a=ardila">Ardila</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" href="?c=cliente&a=mateus">Mateus</a>
<br><br><br>
<table class="table  table-striped  table-hover" id="tabla">
<thead>
    <tr>
<th style="width:180px; background-color: #5DACCD; color:#fff">ID</th>
<th style="width:120px; background-color: #5DACCD; color:#fff">DNI</th>
<th style="width:180px; background-color: #5DACCD; color:#fff">Nombre</th>
        <th style=" background-color: #5DACCD; color:#fff">Apellido</th>
        <th style=" background-color: #5DACCD; color:#fff">Correo</th>
<th style="width:120px; background-color: #5DACCD;  color:#fff">Telefono</th>            
        <th style="width:60px; background-color: #5DACCD; color:#fff"></th>
        <th style="width:60px; background-color: #5DACCD; color:#fff"></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach($this->model->Listar() as $r): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $r->id; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r->dni; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r->Nombre; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r->Apellido; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r->Correo; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $r->Telefono; ?></td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
</table> 
<form action="?c=cliente&a=buscame" method="post" >
<input type="text" name="dni" id="dni"/>
<input type="submit" name="boton" id="boton"/>
</form>
</tbody>
</body>
<script  src="assets/js/datatable.js">  
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: In `view/cliente/cliente.php` - add below `</form>` ->  `<?php $this->model->Buscarme($_POST['dni']); ?>`

Comment: The method `Buscarme` echos the data directly out and I'm assuming this should be stored somewhere to be output in the `foreach($this->model->Listar()...` code.  It's unclear how `Listar()` is intended to work though.

Comment: How do I store the data generated by the method look for me in the foreach?
try to register it in an array but doing the search does not show me anything

Comment: this is model/cliente.php


                $resultado = array();
                $i = 0;
                foreach($res as $row){
      $resultado[$i]['id' ]= $row['id'];

                   $resultado[$i]['dni' ]= $row['dni'];

                   $resultado[$i]['Nombre' ]= $row['Nombre'] ;

                   $resultado[$i]['Apellido' ]=$row['Apellido'];

                   $resultado[$i]['Correo' ]=$row['Correo'] ;

                  $resultado[$i]['Telefono' ]=$row['Telefono'] ;

Comment: this is view view/cliente/cliente.php

<form action="?c=cliente&a=buscar" method="post" >
    
                <input type="text" name="dni" id="dni"/>
                <input type="submit" name="boton" id="boton"/>
    
            </form>
       
            <?php 
              $this->model->Buscarme($_POST['dni']);
              $resultado =  $this->model->resultado;
               print_r($resultado);
            ?>